# NW.js - "Module did not self-register" when page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, nw.js, node-ffi

The first time I run my NW.js application the modules are loaded without errors (and works). If I refresh the page (CTRL+R, F5 or SHIFT+F5) I get the error: `Module did not self-register`. This only happens when `ffi` or `ref` is required.

```
const ffi = require('ffi');
const ref = require('ref');
```

In Electron it works without problems.

Any ideas?

```
nw.js v0.18.8   
Node v7.2.0   
Chromium 54.0.2840.99   
ffi@2.2.0  
ref@1.3.3
```

Here's the full error output:

```
Uncaught Error: Module did not self-register.(…)
  Module._extensions..node  @   VM1704 module.js:640
  Module.load   @   VM1704 module.js:512
  tryModuleLoad @   VM1704 module.js:471
  Module._load  @   VM1704 module.js:463
  Module.require    @   VM1704 module.js:522
  require   @   VM1705 module.js:20
  bindings  @   C:\Users\Even\Desktop\nwjs-sdk-v0.18.8-win-ia32\app\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:76
  (anonymous function)  @   C:\Users\Even\Desktop\nwjs-sdk-v0.18.8-win-ia32\app\node_modules\ref\lib\ref.js:5
  Module._compile   @   VM1704 module.js:595
  Module._extensions..js    @   VM1704 module.js:610
  Module.load   @   VM1704 module.js:512
  tryModuleLoad @   VM1704 module.js:471
  Module._load  @   VM1704 module.js:463
  Module.require    @   VM1704 module.js:522
  require   @   VM1705 module.js:20
  (anonymous function)  @   C:\Users\Even\Desktop\nwjs-sdk-v0.18.8-win-ia32\app\node_modules\ffi\lib\ffi.js:6
  Module._compile   @   VM1704 module.js:595
  Module._extensions..js    @   VM1704 module.js:610
  Module.load   @   VM1704 module.js:512
  tryModuleLoad @   VM1704 module.js:471
  Module._load  @   VM1704 module.js:463
  Module.require    @   VM1704 module.js:522
  require   @   VM1705 module.js:20
  (anonymous function)  @   C:\Users\Even\Desktop\nwjs-sdk-v0.18.8-win-ia32\app\FsuipcMonitor.js:22
  Module._compile   @   VM1704 module.js:595
  Module._extensions..js    @   VM1704 module.js:610
  Module.load   @   VM1704 module.js:512
  tryModuleLoad @   VM1704 module.js:471
  Module._load  @   VM1704 module.js:463
  Module.require    @   VM1704 module.js:522
  require   @   VM1705 module.js:20
  self.require  @   VM1758:11
  (anonymous function)  @   mainpage_renderer.js:15
```

Comment: How did you install those two addons?

Comment: @mscdex `npm install ffi`  and `npm install ref` followed by `nw-gyp rebuild --target=0.18.8 --arch=ia32` from each of the two folders `node_modules/ffi` and `node_modules/ref`

Comment: I opened an issue on the nw.js github and it appears to be a bug in nw.js. Hopefully it will be fixed soon!